# Как поправить кодировку данных от скрипта .cgi

Tags: c, cgi

Написал скрипт на языке C - и при выводе данных, кодировка сбивается...Вот что выдает браузер в результате выполнения скрипта[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот код

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void){
char *remote_addr = getenv("REMOTE_ADDR");
char *query_string = getenv("QUERY_STRING");

printf("Content-type: text/html\n\n");

printf("<!DOCTYPE html>");
printf("<html lang='ru'>");
printf("<head>");
printf("<title>Работа с переменными окружения</title>");
printf("<meta charset='utf-8'>");
printf("</head>");
printf("<body>");
printf("<h1>3.Мы знаем о вас всё!</hl>");
printf("<p>Baш IP-aдpec: %s</p>", remote_addr);    
printf("<p>Bот параметры коотрые в ввели: %s</p>", query_string);
printf("</body></html>");

}
```

Comment: Основная кодировка воспринимаемая браузером - это передаваемая в заголовке Content-type, а не та что всякими метами в самом теле html. https://www.w3.org/International/articles/http-charset/index.ru

Comment: И текст вашего скрипта ведь набран в utf8 ?